# Creating an array of objects within a class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm fairly new to Swift and iOS programming and only have a rough understanding of classes and objects.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Step {
    var notation: String
    init (notation: String) {
        self.notation = notation
    }
}

class AlgorithmMaker {   
    let F = Step(notation: "F")
    let Fi = Step(notation: "F'")
    let F2 = Step(notation: "F2")
    var frontArray = [F, Fi, F2]
}
```

I'm trying to create an array of objects from class "Step" inside my AlgorithmMaker class. However, Xcode keeps giving me the error:

'AlgorithmMaker.Type' does not have a member named 'F'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're an initializing the class members the current scope is the *class scope*, so when you do

```
var frontArray = [F, Fi, F2]
```

you're actually doing

```
var frontArray = [self.F, self.Fi, self.F2]
```

and `self` is the class itself in this scope, i.e. `AlgorithmMaker` in this case.

As a solution, you can use an initializer and do

```
class AlgorithmMaker {   
  let f = Step(notation: "F")
  let fi = Step(notation: "F'")
  let f2 = Step(notation: "F2")
  var frontArray: [Step]

  init() {
    frontArray = [f, fi, f2]  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything in that class with:

```
var frontArray = [Step(notation: "F"), Step(notation: "F'"), Step(notation: "F2")]
```

Or replace your frontArray with `var frontArray : [Step] = []` and add:

```
override init() {
    frontArray = [F, Fi, F2]
}
```

The problem is that declaring frontArray as `[F, Fi, F2]` is technically a piece of logic, meaning you can't put it outside of a method of a class.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you can't call other properties during initialization and you are doing that inside.